# How can Java compute the value of a variable using an assigned expression?

Tags: java, variables

I am studying "*Learning Java Through Games*" by Lubomir Stanchev and there is this problem I can't solve.

We will randomly ask the player to either add, multiply, or subtract one-digit numbers (we skip division because the result of dividing two numbers is not an integer). The game should ask 10 math questions and record the answers. At the end, the game should tell the player how well they did, that is, how many questions they answered correctly.

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arithmetic {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, x, y, z, answer, a, counter = 0;
        char sign;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            y = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            a = (int)(Math.random() * 3);//random sign

            if(a==0){
                sign = '+';
            } else if(a == 1) {
                sign = '-';
            } else {
                sign = '*';
            }

            System.out.print(x + " " + sign + " " + y + " = ");
            z = keyboard.nextInt();          
            answer = x + sign + y; 

            System.out.println(answer);

            if(z == answer){
                System.out.println("Correct");
                counter++;                
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");       
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You answered "+counter+" questions correctly");
    }
}
```

There is a problem with the value of variable answer. It won't compute the expression because x&y are integers and variable sign is a char. I'm coming from JS so I find this odd. In JS, expressions are automatically computed or concatenated regardless of its type. I'm in Chapter 3 so I haven't studied `parseInt` thing, which I believe wont work for char.

Thanks for the help.

This is now my updated answer:

```
public class Arithmetic {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, x, y, z, answer, a, counter=0;
        char sign;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            x = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            y = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            a = (int)(Math.random() * 3);//random sign

            if(a==0){
                sign = '+';
                answer = x + y;
            } else if(a==1) {
                sign = '-';
                answer = x - y;
            } else {
                sign = '*';
                answer = x * y;
            }

            System.out.print(x+" "+sign+" "+y+" = ");
            z = keyboard.nextInt();          

            if(z==answer){
                System.out.println("Correct");
                counter++;                
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");       
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You answered "+counter+" questions correctly");
    }
}
```

It did compile!!!

Comment: "In JS, expressions are automatically computed or concatenated regardless of its type" - Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Nayuki https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do an if/else if/else on the `sign` and adjust `answer` accordingly:

```
if (sign == '+') {
    answer = x + y;
} else if (sign == '-') {
    answer = x - y;
} else if (sign == '*') {
    answer = x * y;
} else {
    System.err.println("Unknown operator: " + sign);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(sign) {
case('+'): 
    answer = x + y;
    break;
case('-'):
    answer = x - y;
    break;
case('*'):
    answer = x * y;
    break;
default:
    System.err.println("Unknown operator: " + sign);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, x, y, z, answer, a, counter = 0;
    char sign;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        y = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        a = (int) (Math.random() * 3);//random sign

        if (a == 0) {
            sign = '+';
        } else if (a == 1) {
            sign = '-';
        } else {
            sign = '*';
        }

        System.out.print(x + " " + sign + " " + y + " = ");
        z = keyboard.nextInt();


        //Using Ternary operator
        answer = sign == '+' ? (x +y) : (sign == '-' ? (x-y) : x * y);

        System.out.println(answer);

        if (z == answer) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            counter++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You answered " + counter + " questions correctly");
}
```